# Error sending email in R

Tags: r, email

While sending email using R, got the following error.

```
library(sendmailR)


from <- "<boralsoumya@gmail.com>"
to <- "<amarnath.boral@gmail.com>"
subject <- "Performance Result"
body <- "This is the result of the test:"                     
mailControl=list(smtpServer="ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM")

sendmail(from=from,to=to,subject=subject,msg=body,control=mailControl)
```

Error

```
Error in wait_for(250) : 
  SMTP Error: 5.7.1 [45.64.236.186] The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized to
```

Saw this link but of not much help : https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10336?hl=en

How to solve this ?

Comment: See your mail administrator in order to allow your server to send.

Comment: The `IP Address` of the PC you are using to send email is not to use `SMTP` server from `google`. I suggest if you can get access to `SMTP` Server of your own organisation then use it to send email.